# How to draw contour for a document in OpenCV.js?

Tags: opencv

I'm a beginner with OpenCV, I stumbled with a problem to draw 4 point contours around document image, I followed this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/) and this example from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528462/opencv-js-perspective-transform) for OpenCV.js

Getting the following error:

```
BindingError {name: "BindingError", message: "Cannot pass "[object Object]" as a MatVector", 
stack: "BindingError: Cannot pass "[object Object]....
```

Not sure how to correctly pass contours that I found to a `drawContours` method

Here is the code example :

```
 let color = new cv.Scalar(0, 255, 0);
  let edgeDetected = new cv.Mat();
  let contours = new cv.MatVector();
  let hierarchy = new cv.Mat();
  cv.Canny(img, edgeDetected, 100, 200, 3, true);
  cv.findContours(edgeDetected, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

  let foundContour = new cv.MatVector();

  //Get area for all contours so we can find the biggest
  let sortableContours = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    let cnt = contours.get(i);
    let area = cv.contourArea(cnt, false);
    let perim = cv.arcLength(cnt, false);

    sortableContours.push({ areaSize: area, perimiterSize: perim, contour: cnt });
  }

  sortableContours = sortableContours.sort((item1, item2) => { return (item1.areaSize > item2.areaSize) ? -1 : (item1.areaSize < item2.areaSize) ? 1 : 0; }).slice(0, 5);

  //Ensure the top area contour has 4 corners (NOTE: This is not a perfect science and likely needs more attention)
  let approx = new cv.Mat();
  cv.approxPolyDP(sortableContours[0].contour, approx, .05 * sortableContours[0].perimiterSize, true);

  if (approx.rows == 4) {
    console.log('Found a 4-corner approx');
    foundContour = approx;
  }
  else{
    console.log('No 4-corner large contour!');
    return;
  }

  //Find the corners
  let corner1 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[0], foundContour.data32S[1]);
  let corner2 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[2], foundContour.data32S[3]);
  let corner3 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[4], foundContour.data32S[5]);
  let corner4 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[6], foundContour.data32S[7]);

  //Order the corners
  let cornerArray = new cv.MatVector();
  cornerArray = [{ corner: corner1 }, { corner: corner2 }, { corner: corner3 }, { corner: corner4 }];
  //Sort by Y position (to get top-down)
  cornerArray.sort((item1, item2) => { 
    return (item1.corner.y < item2.corner.y) ? -1 : (item1.corner.y > item2.corner.y) ? 1 : 0; 
  }).slice(0, 5);
  
  for (c of cornerArray) {
    cv.drawContours(img, c.corner, -1, color, 1, cv.LINE_8, hierarchy, 100);
  }

  cv.imshow('canvasOutput', img);
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: show all the error throwback

Answer (score 0):

I cant see where you initialized opencv. Do this

```js
const cv = require("./opencv.js");
cv['onRuntimeInitialized']=()=>{
  let mat = new cv.Mat();
  console.log(mat.size()); //use this line to test if opencv was initialized successfully
  mat.delete();
};
```

Start with this snippet

Comment: it is initialized i just didn't include this in my question

Comment: In that case try doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298228/opencv-js-how-to-draw-a-subset-of-contours). Someone had similar problems